# Signal is unable to initialise to integer value in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

In the following code, I have initialized cipher_temp2 to the integer value 1. But when I simulate my code, I see the value of cipher_temp2 to be initialized to 0 instead of. I am unable to figure out where I went wrong.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity ciphercalculation is
      Port ( Msg_temp2 : in integer;
                cipher : out integer);
end ciphercalculation;

architecture Behavioral of ciphercalculation is
CONSTANT e1: std_logic_vector(0 TO 2) := ('1', '0', '1');
CONSTANT Pk:integer:=377;
CONSTANT le:integer:=2;
Signal cipher_temp2:integer:=1;
begin
process(cipher_temp2,Msg_temp2)
begin
for i in 0 to le loop
        if (e1(i)= '0') then
            cipher_temp2<=((cipher_temp2*cipher_temp2) mod Pk);
        else
            cipher_temp2<=((cipher_temp2*cipher_temp2) mod Pk);
            cipher_temp2<=((cipher_temp2*Msg_temp2)mod Pk);
        end if;
    end loop;

cipher<=cipher_temp2;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Post a minimal testbench that demonstrates this. Also mention which simulator/version you are using. In ghdl I see it being initialised to 1. Then the process is activated, which  sets it to 340, then 0, both at 0 ms.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/B2Lgj here is the screenshot of the simulation. I used Vivado 2014.4

Comment: And that won't stow you what you need to see, as I explained.

Comment: I didn't understand where exactly did I go wrong?

Comment: You didn't go wrong. It initialised to 1 - at least in my simulator.

Comment: I'll try with ISE too. Could you tell me, what is the value of output(cipher) you are getting?

Comment: I already answered that.

Answer (score 0):

First off I would like to suggest a few things starting with using `std_logic_vector` or `std_logic` on your port mapping. It will make it much easier when you have different modules or even have to interface Verilog/VHDL/SystemVerilog. Also having a clock on your interface will make things run smoother and make it easier to debug.

Now then, you should be aware that the simulation is not a true simulation of an FPGA, but the Xilinx tools try their best. In an FPGA there is a signal dirven to all the logic on power on, the GSR, or Global Set/Reset.  This signal dictates how every wire/register/leaf/cell is going to be initialized to.

One issue that you should always be aware of when using initial values that would be set by GSR is that GSR is an asynchronous event, that is it happens without regard to clocking.

In general the value should be initialized to what you dictate in the declaration, however because it is a simulation (and using vivado's engine) it may not simulate the way you think it will. 
If you synthesize this with Xilinx, also note that initial values are not part of the synthesis standards, the tools should put the value in a LUT for you. While you are simulating however, the tools will try to act as if it's an FPGA, however it will only simulate the stimuli that you give it. 
This could be your issue as the vivado simulator is a bit better than the ISE (although they still use the same codename, the vivado engine has improvements).

To get around this I suggest you have a simple reset condition that dictates what your initial value should be. Also note that the Xilnix standard is to hold reset for ~`5us`.